# Testing angularJs Controller with jasmine generate TypeError:Can't read property 'locations_id' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I wan't to write a test for a controller function in my project. A simple test I'm trying to do is just to verify if the $scope.locations contains the parameter location_id but it doesn't work for me. I also verify if an element of the $scope.locations is set to a value but I get always the same error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'location_id' of undefined

The function code is :

```
App.controller('LocationsController',
        ['$http', '$rootScope','$scope',
           function ($http, $rootScope, $scope) {
                $scope.locations = [];
                $scope.addLocation = function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $scope.locations.push({'location_id': $scope.location.locations_id, 'conditions': '', 'status': 'ENABLED', 'title': '', 'description': ''});
                };
```

My test code is :

```
describe('LocationsController', function() {
         var $scope, $rootScope,controller ;
         beforeEach(module('App'));
         beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, $controller) {
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        event=jasmine.createSpyObj('event',['preventDefault']);

             controller = $controller('LocationsController', 
         { $scope: $scope});}));
         it('should set addLocation function',function(){
             expect($scope.addLocation).toBeDefined();});
         it('should call addLocation ',function(){
            $scope.addLocation(event);
           expect($scope.locations).toContain("location_id");
          // expect($scope.locations.status).toBe("ENABLED");
         }); });
```

can someone help me to find what is the source of my problem?